# Web Performance - jQuery fetching of HTML, CSS, JS, and IMGs

Tags: jquery, performance, caching

I have an app with about 10 HTML, 4 CSS, 8 JS, and 15 IMG (PNG/JPG) files.  I want to make this site very responsive and fast (ie. a great user experience).

Therefore, on ANY initial page load, I would like the browser to cache EVERY asset from the site asynchronously WITHOUT a 'browser busy'.  According to Steve Souders (Google) I need to use XHR Eval or XHR Injection to avoid the 'browser busy'.  See slide 23 of [Even Faster Web Sites](https://sites.google.com/site/io/even-faster-web-sites).

I know I can use XHR Eval or XHR Injection for Javascript.  Can I use it for HTML, CSS, etc?

I am trying code like this (with jQuery), but can't quite get it to work:

```
$.ajax({ url:"/blog", cache:true, dataType:"text" });
$.ajax({ url:"/about", cache:true, dataType:"text" });
$.ajax({ url:"/blog/main.css", cache:true, dataType:"text" });
$.ajax({ url:"/about/logo.png", cache:true, dataType:"text" });
$.ajax({ url:"/blog/social.js", cache:true, dataType:"text" });
```

Am I way off or is this the right track towards a fully cached site with a fast user experience?

Comment: 1. You can use an icon sprite for the images, and a minify algorithm for css, and javascript. These would reduce the static files overhead significantly

Answer (score 0):

Before you even think of micro-optimizations, start with macro-optimizations:

- Make sure Gzip compression is enabled on your server.
- Combine and minify your CSS and JS files into single files.
- Combine all of your small images into a single big image to make a sprite. This will reduce the number of requests.
- Choose the optimal format for your images and remove unnecessary metadata information to save space.

Comment: I will do those things as well, but there will still be separate HTML pages that I would like to present the user with as soon as they click on a page.  So, will this work for HTML docs?

Comment: @JustinCloud: What do you mean by "this"?

Comment: By 'this' I mean, can I asynchronously load the HTML pages without a 'browser busy' or the user noticing. so that for example:  The user for the first time comes to example.com, it takes 3 second to load (say from a 3G phone browser which is slower), the user spends 10 seconds reading there, then clicks on faq, the FAQ page loads in 0.1 seconds because its already cached.  The user (on 3G) has a great experience browsing all around the site quickly.